# Voltage shifting from 5V to 1.5V

Tags: voltage, conversion

I have a 5V TTL which is basically a trigger output that I want to give to an FPGA I/O pin which takes 1.5V, 10mA. What's the best way to do it and what's a quick way to do it ? I was able to look up techniques on converting from 5V to 3.3V but not many on 5V to 1.5V.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a [resistor potential divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

[image]

Vout = Vin x \$\dfrac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$

Comment: This is the quickest way I could possibly get running. What are the drawbacks of using a potential divider in this case ?

Comment: Don't use high value resistors if digital speed is high because track capacitance will slow the signal down. Values around 1k are worth a try first and if you have an o-scope then look at the signals to see if lower values are needed. Unlikely to need less than 100 ohms though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dual-supply logic level translator if you have a 1.5V supply available and speed is important to you. For example, a [74LVC1T45](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC_LVCH1T45.pdf).

[image]